# Element Classpath not allowed here in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, classpath

I have below configuration in my pom.xml. Project with this pom.xml builds fine in Eclipse & also when i run mvn install, mvn compile from command line. But only in  intellij IDEA it shows an error as "Element Classpath not allowed here"

```
<configuration>
<includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
<includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
<classpath />
<mainClass>com.example.check.bts.executor.Starter</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

it would be helpful if someone could suggest what could be done to resolve this error on Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching around, I came to assume that you are using the exec-maven-plugin. I then read the example example [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html) and saw that you are not supposed to have `<classpath />` there, hence why IntelliJ gives you that error.

Comment: Ok. Still not clear why no error in eclipse or any failure when running from command line

Comment: @Raj I think they may just be ignoring it, but IntelliJ is being picky.